# Why do I get Floor and Ceiling in my output despite my assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify the following expression.

```
Sum[
  Binomial[2 k, m] (1 + (-1)^m)/2 Beta[(1 + m)/2, (n - 2)/2] 
    (Gamma[(1 + m)/2] Gamma[1/2 (-1 + 2 k - m + n)])^2 , 
  {m, 0, 2 k}]
```

Before doing it, I first set the `$Assumptions = {n ∈ Integers, k ∈ Integers};` since I know `n` and `k` are integers.

The answer I got from *Mathematica* v10 was rather complicated. However, one thing I found strange was that the solution contains `Floor[k]` and `Ceiling[-k]` that are clearly just `k` and `-k` since they are integers.

What is more strange thing is I get an error if I try to further simplify it. 
What is the precise way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Add `Assumptions -> $Assumptions` to your `Sum[]`

Comment: Or encase the Sum in the Assumptions: `Assuming[$Assumptions, Sum[Binomial[2 k, m] (1 + (-1)^m)/2 Beta[(1 + m)/2, (n - 2)/2] (Gamma[(1 + m)/2] Gamma[1/2 (-1 + 2 k - m + n)])^2, {m, 0, 2 k}]] gives a simpler answer.

Comment: @belisarius Oh know, I thought I did't know I have to put such assumptions in each expression that I later evaluate. Then, what is the reason we set `$Assumptions` if we still have to put `Assumptions` to the expression? (PS. I tried your solution but I still habe a problem).

Comment: @bills Yes your suggestion really simplified my expression. Thank you. But I'm still quite confused. Why should I put such additional `Assuming` function even though I have already set `$Assumptions`? I've oberseved that `$Assumptions` worked quite well in my experience. Do you have a criteria that I should additionally put `Assumption`?

Comment: @bills This is strange. Surely using the `Assumptions` option to `Sum`, setting the global `$Assumptions` and using `Assuming` should all have the same effect?

Comment: @Sungmin, rhermans' answer seems correct to me.  Is there a reason you haven't accepted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) is the default setting for the Assumptions option used in such functions as `Simplify`, `Refine`, and `Integrate`.

It expects statements such as `$Assumptions = a < 0 && b < 0}`, using the wrong syntax  `$Assumptions = {n ∈ Integers, k ∈ Integers}` actually breaks the use of `Simplify`.

The correct approach should have been

```
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && n ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers
```

and then use `FullSimplify`.

As pointed out in the comments, there is no need to change the global definitions and you are better off by using

```
Assuming[
{n, k} ∈ Integers
,FullSimplify[
  Sum[
    Binomial[2 k, m] (1 + (-1)^m) 2 Beta[(1 + m)/2, (n - 2) 2] (Gamma[(1 + m)/2] Gamma[1/2 (-1 + 2 k - m + n)])^2
    , {m, 0, 2 k}
]]]
```

Comment: +1, but I would say that the use of `FullSimplify` is optional. It simplifies only a little, while the main point is the syntax of `$Assumptions`.  Also note that `Assuming[{n ∈ Integers, k ∈ Integers}, $Assumptions]` shows `Assuming` rewrites the assumptions by replacing `List` with `And`.